# Django: Getting a link to admin page in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, admin

I'm trying to add a link in my django template to a page handled by the default admin console. The setup is below, I don't believe the {% url %} part of the equation is right and I'm getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'profile_ProfileModel' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.

How do I correct this and link to the admin console from the template.

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:profiles_ProfileModel' %}">Profiles</a>
```

profiles.models.py

```
class Profile (models.Model)
```

profiles.admin.py

```
class ProfileAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin)
    admin.site.register (Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns("", url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

Answer (score 9):

The name of the changelist url for a model is `{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_changelist`. In your case, if the app_label is `profiles` and the model in `Profile`, the view name would be `profiles_profile_changelist`.

Try the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:profiles_profile_changelist' %}">Profiles</a>
```

See the Django docs on [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) for more information.

Comment: thanks, i'm still receiving a 'reverse with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found' error though.

Comment: What's the name of your app? What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the server after updating the code. Apart from that, I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure it out.